# check the same char in strg and remove and split from underscore in PHP?

Tags: php, string

Hello I have one string **"22A_n22A"** and i want to remove the same character from this string and want to split from "_" to two string like **22A** and **n22A**.
    i tried it but did not get any solution.
    final out put i want like **22A_n22A** to **(n)22AA**

```
    <?php 
     function conti($str,$case_sensitive = false) {


         //if($com1 = preg_replace("/\b(\w+)\s+\\1\b/i", "$1", $newval)) 
         if(strcmp($case_sensitive , $case_sensitive) === 0 ) 
         {

        $pieces = explode("_", $str);
        $str1 =  $pieces[0];
        $str2 =  $pieces[1];

        $ary1 = str_split($str1);
        $ary2 = str_split($str2);

        if (isset($case_sensitive))
        {
          $ary1 = array_map('strtolower',$ary1);
          $ary2 = array_map('strtolower',$ary2);
        }

         $com =  implode('',array_intersect($ary1,$ary2));
         $diff = implode('',array_merge(array_diff($ary1, $ary2),array_diff($ary2, $ary1)));
         $int = (int) filter_var($com, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
         $onlystr = preg_replace('/\d/', '', $com);
         $newval= '('.$diff.')'.$int.$onlystr.$onlystr;
       // $com1 = preg_replace("/\b(\w+)\s+\\1\b/i", "$1", $str);
         echo '<pre><h1>';
         echo 'new value:';
         print_r($newval);
         echo "<br>";    
                  echo "<br>"; 
                  echo "<br>"; 
          echo 'new value:';
          print_r($com);
           echo "<br>";
          echo 'new diff:';
          print_r($diff);
         echo '</pre>';
         return $newval;
          }

       else {    
         echo '<pre><h1>';
         echo 'oldvalue:';    
         print_r($str);
         echo '</pre>';
         return $str;
         }
     }
      echo(conti('71A_n71A'));
    //  echo(conti('66A_n66A'));


    ?>
```

Comment: why (n)22AA and not (n)22A or (n)2222AA ?

Comment: because it's requirement i need 22A_n22A full string to (n)22AA remove the same char and put in the one

Comment: @joki3 Do you have any other real examples with the related result that you can share?

Comment: Will the first number and digit group always match the second (e.g: `22A_n22A`) or can they be different (e.g: `22A_n22B`)? It's important to make that clear, and if it's the latter case, to show some examples with expected output.

Comment: @PatrickQ I do not have any real example but i tried via phpfidle online but did not work

Comment: @joki3 I mean example strings other than "22A_n22A", and what the corresponding results should be.

Comment: @DarraghEnright  22A_n22A this  strings to i need (n)22AA this output 
remove the one 22 and put to gather like 22AA and n became (n) this.

Comment: @PatrickQ corresponding results must be (n)22AA

Comment: @PatrickQ other example like 78A_n78A should be output (n)78AA

Comment: So, `22A_n22B` becomes `(n)22AB` correct? What happens if the original string is `22A_n33B`—can that happen and if so, what do you want the result to be?

Comment: @joki3 Okay, so is the first part always repeated after the "n"?  Is it possible that you would have something like "12B_n23F"?

Comment: @DarraghEnright no always Original string but be same character first and second like 65A_n66A to put like (n)66AA.  we have there only A common and digit was different like 22,98,77,71 or ect

Comment: @PatrickQ yes first part was repeated after "n" and there would not have different like 12B_n23F there always we have same character A like 45A_n45A  means same digit with same character

Comment: Okay, so you are ignoring everything except the last character from the first chunk?

Comment: @DarraghEnright yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in your comments your requirement is to:

- Split the string on `_`
- Pluck the last character from the first chunk of the string and append that to the end of the second string
- Wrap the first character of the second chunk of the string in parentheses

For example, `65A_n66A` becomes `(n)66AA`.

You can do this with by performing `explode()` on the original string, extracting the parts you need and piecing them back together in your desired format:

```
function format($string) {

    list($first, $second) = explode('_', $string);

    return sprintf('(%s)%s%s', 
        $second[0],
        substr($second, 1),
        $first[strlen($first) - 1]
    );
}
```

This yields:

```
echo format('22A_n22A'); // (n)22AA
echo format('11A_n22B'); // (n)22BA
echo format('65A_n66A'); // (n)66AA
```

Hope this helps :)